# Binding to current datacontext with default values 

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

iv'e got an image nested inside a button

```
   <ListBox>                    
      <ListBox.ItemsSource>
          <Binding Path="Peers"></Binding>
      </ListBox.ItemsSource>

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <ListBoxItem>                               
                  <Button  x:Name="btn_InviteToPlay" Click="btn_InviteToPlay_Click">                                         
                     <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{Binding  GameStatus,Converter={StaticResource MyGameStatusToIconConverter}}" x:Name="img_invitation"></Image>
                      </Button.Content>
                   </Button>
                </ListBoxItem>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>              
 </ListBox>
```

when i click btn_InviteToPlay i attempt to change the image's datacontext to an instance of **Game** And Bind the Image's Source to the Game's GameStatus Property.

```
    private void btn_InviteToPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                        
        Game game = new Game(){ GameStatus = GameStatus.Waiting};
        img.DataContext = game;
    }
```

this binding does not work ,

first of all the DataContext for the image is initially the DataContext of it's Ancestor which i do not wan't to apply to the Image .

my question is :

(1)how do i apply a default value before the image datacontext is given any context , while ignoring the ancestor's DataContext Since the image is nested inside an ItemsControl Item .

(2)in general i was unable to apply a binding for for the current DataContext 
   ( a binding with Game as Source and GameStatus as Path ) , so i'm looking for the correct way this is done.

i believe the way to go is to bind each Image to a default Instance Of Game .

iv'e attempted this in markup :
in my resources :

```
   <local:Game x:Key="DefaultGame" />
```

the Image:

```
   <Image  Source="{Binding Source=DefaultGame,Path=GameStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyGameStatusToIconConverter}}" x:Name="img_invitation"></Image>
```

this does not work as well , any ideas .
also i thought of doing this in code but couldn't figure out how 
since all i do is give the containing panel it's datacontext and all is derived from there.

Comment: This is a very ugly sprawling question.  Try to remove all unneeded portions and distill it down to something more manageable.  If you have multiple questions it is best to ask multiple questions (multiple posts) instead of putting three questions into one post.

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Is there/should there be only only Game instance at any given time? Your goal is hidden somewhere behind this lengthy post, it's not easy to find it.

Comment: @Mangnus  i realize this is lengthy, i just wanted to give the observer a complete overview of the situations
in sort i want to bind an Image Source to a path according to the value of the GameStatus and apply a default value to begin with since 
Game only exist later on and so it as no source ,
also there could be a case of ambiguity with datacontext at start
since the DataContext is set later and the image is nested with  in an ItemsControl bound to a list.

Comment: Well, in that case I don't see any reason to switch the DataContext. Create an instance of the Game object up front, and by default set it to a default GameStatus. Your Converter should then return a proper path for the default GameStatus.

Comment: iv'e attempted this in markup 

  <local:Game x:Key="DefaultGame" />
  <Image  Source="{Binding Source=DefaultGame,Path=GameStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyGameStatusToIconConverter}}" x:Name="img_invitation"></Image>

any ideas why this doesn't work .?

Comment: Try adding this namespace: `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"`, and in your binding, add `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`. When you debug your program, WPF will dump a bunch of info to the Output Window (or Immediate Window, depending on your settings) that will make it much easier to see what WPF is trying and what it's actually finding.